# CDC area size in logical units?

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-studio-2008, mfc, gdi

I'm using function [CDC::Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8w4fzfxf.aspx) and it uses logical coordinates.
But I want to know how large is the area on which I draw, so I can for example draw rectangle 10% of area width.

How can I get dimensions of coordinate system from CDC?

Comment: Just dividing the width by 10 will give you the desired partial width, still in logical coordinates of course.

Comment: @MSalters but how to determine rect size(occupying all drawing area) when we have 100% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, a Windows device context does not keep track of the boundaries of the object it's attached to. [`GetBoundsRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah4scb3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) might give you something useful, or it might not, depending on the circumstances. Using the CWnd object and calling [`GetClientRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkzy4k3x.aspx) is the most reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GetClientRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkzy4k3x.aspx) to get the client size of the window (ie the drawing space for your window).

Answer (score 0):

Logical coordinates are important only when your mapping mode is not `MM_TEXT`, in that case you would need to use [CDC::LPtoDP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca9sb0yt.aspx).

You should be able to use the example in the link in your question except that
instead of `rect.DeflateRect(20, 20);`
use `rect.right /= 10; rect.bottom /= 10;`